# How to reset chapter and section counter with \part*

Tags: latex, counter, reset, sections

Sorry for bad english

I have a problem with my Latex code (I'm not very good in coding). I want an output like this:

```
 Part I

   Chapter I
   Chapter II

 Part II

   Chapter I
   Chapter II
```

I also wanted to create a box around my title of the parts , this doesn't work like I wanted, so I used \part* and \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{PART I} (to write the line in the table of content).So the code is:

```
 \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
 \part*{\begin{center}
  PART I
  \end{center}}
   \end{minipage}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{PART I}
  \vspace{0.7cm}
```

I saw this methode to reset the counter of the chapters:

```
  \makeatletter
  \@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
  \makeatother
```

but this doesn't work, I think it's due to use of \part*.

Has anyone an idea? THNANKS!

Hope the example bellow can help:)

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,]{report}  
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \newpage
   \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
   \part*{\begin{center}
   INTRODUCTION
   \end{center}}
    \end{minipage}}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{INTRODUCTION}
    \vspace{0.7cm}

    \chapter{Hello}
     \section{my}

     \newpage
     \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \part*{\begin{center}
     CONCLUSION
     \end{center}}
     \end{minipage}}
     \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{CONCLUSION}
      \vspace{0.7cm}

     \chapter{name}
     \section{is}

      \end{document}
```

Comment: please make a [mre]

Comment: I added an example, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know the solution for `\part`, how about simply using this and make it look like `\part*`? This has the advantage that you could add the boxes around the part titles automatically.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,]{report}  

\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\part}[frame]
  {\normalfont}
  {}
  {8pt}
  {\Large\bfseries\filcenter}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{part}[0em]
    {\vspace{2em}\large\bfseries\sffamily\relax}
    {\contentslabel[\relax]{0em}}{}{\hfill\contentspage}

 \usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother 


 \begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \part{INTRODUCTION}
    \chapter{Hello}
     \section{my}

   \part{CONCLUSION}
     \chapter{name}
     \section{is}

      \end{document}
```

Comment: YES! It's working thank you soooo much, you made my day:)